# Javascript/jQuery newbie mistake with mouseenter event causing syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to apply a style when the `mouseenter` event is triggered, but if I uncomment the following  untouched selector - even the document ready stops working.

```
<body>
<div id="1" class="button untouched"></div>
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("JQuery is working");
});

/*
$(".untouched").mouseenter($function(){
    $(this).addClass("touched");
});
*/
</script>
</body>
```

I am following the example found at:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

And I get the [following error in Firebug](http://jsfiddle.net/cxeFa/):

```
missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   

$(".untouched").mouseenter($function(){
```

Since it does not work, I've made a mistake, but I don't know what. All I know is that none of my code works if I let that run. I downloaded the latest 1.7.2 version of jQuery, which I know is available on the page because the `alert()` runs with the other commented out.

Comment: This is a Javascript syntax error, not a jQuery problem.

Comment: @JaredFarrish How could I have detected this typo - I am used to compiled languages?

Comment: Thanks everyone - I knew it was a stupid typo somewhere - without knowing the syntax though its hard to spot.

Comment: I would use Firebug or Chrome Console.

Comment: @AdrianCornish Run your code in a browser with a console (most modern browsers have one built in). I use Chrome and hit F12. If you got to the console tab in the Developer Tools that come up you'll see any Javascript errors.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Cool - was not getting a normal jscript error but with firebug I get "missing ) after argument list"
Thanks again

Comment: Keep in mind a lot of syntax errors are misreported due to the nature of syntax errors (without syntax, what does it really mean?) and Javascript's dynamic capabilities. So when you end up with something like that, where the error proves not to be the issue, try isolating your code parts and see what you get. I often use http://jsfiddle.net to do this, just using the run command.

Comment: Since I imagine this won't be going anywhere, I edited the question to make it more specific to the actual problem it describes. Feel free to correct anything I got wrong.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Agree - much better edit. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script the `$(".untouched")` part should be within the `ready` function. Also,

`mouseenter($function(){` the $ sign is not correct.

Your final script should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("JQuery is working");

    $(".untouched").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("touched");
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no reason to move the code into `$(document).ready`. `alert("JQuery is working");` doesn't need to be inside it either in fact.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. - You mean the reason it's not needed in the `doc.ready` is because the element it's referencing is already in the DOM?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yeah. Why would you wait for the entire DOM to be ready when you could do it right away :)

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. - I wanted to make sure that was clarified. The original comment, for a beginner, could easily be confusing. My opinion, this question should be closed as too local.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - maybe not close - as syntax errors always seem unique to the poster - it may help someone. Up to you.

Comment: @AdrianCornish - With so many like this, it's either a duplicate or of low value overall. It would be very hard for someone to intentionally find this question for their problem, so it's just noise IMO. No big deal. Also, I would review PaulP.R.O.'s answer, his suggestion is probably a good one.

Comment: Go for it @JaredFarrish - it answered my question :-)

Answer (score 4):

No need for the $ in front of the function. Also, the mouseenter event function code should be inside the document ready.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         alert("JQuery is working");

         $(".untouched").mouseenter(function(){
             $(this).addClass("touched");
         });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `$` you shouldn't in front of the word `function`. You probably also want to remove the `untouched` class:

```
$(".untouched").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("untouched").addClass("touched");
});
```

Comment: I was wondering about removing the class - since the add is relying on CSS replace rules. I am still trying to get my head round jquery syntax - from a c++ world :-) - I previously had something similar as 2 LOCS - but that seems more in jquery style.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily perform this right from css

```
    .untouched 
       {
       background: green;
      }

    .untouched :hover
      {
       background: blue
       }
```

In JQuery if you want to use .mouseover you need to functions - one for when you put the mouse over, one for when the mouse isn't over.  This is easier in css , there is just a :hover filter

```
       $('.untouched').mouseover(function() {
               $(this).addClass('touched');
                     });
       $('.untuoched').mouseout(function() {
              $(this).removeClass('touched');
                      });
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Actually I wanted to create the sort of Android type lock screen by passing the mouse over the grid to select a pattern - I simplified because it was not working. Once the 'password' is picked I wanted to unlock a new screen.